# C# Regex Get values after the specific Character but need to check prevous character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create regex for following scenario

`name like %name` -- match and extract %name

`name like '%name'` -- should not match as it has ' before %

`name like ' %name'` -- should not match as previous character is ' ( ignoring space )

`name like%name` match and extract %name

This is what I got [^']%\w+ but this dosen't cover last two cases

Comment: You're pretty close, but I don't understand the 4th case exactly. `^'?%(\w+)'?` might be enough.

Comment: Your complete lack of code quoting with ``` makes what you consider input and what you're explaining look the same.

Comment: Sorry I will edit the question havent used stackoverflow for a long time

Comment: @JonathonChase in 4th case it will extract e%name I want to just get %name. I can remove it using string operations but wanted to check if there is a cleaner way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may suit your needs, although it does depend on the string being prefixed with `name like`.

```
void Main()
{
    var strings = new string[] {"name like %name", "name like '%name'", "name like ' %name'", "name like%name"};
    var regex = new Regex("^name like ?(%\\w+)");
    foreach (var item in strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"string: \"{item}\" matches: {regex.IsMatch(item)} extracted: {(regex.Match(item).Groups.Count > 0 ? regex.Match(item).Groups[1].Value : string.Empty)}");
    }
    //Output:
    //string: "name like %name" matches: True extracted: %name
    //string: "name like '%name'" matches: False extracted: 
    //string: "name like ' %name'" matches: False extracted: 
    //string: "name like%name" matches: True extracted: %name
}
```

The regex breakdown is:

`^name like`: a string starting with `name like`

`?`: an optional space

`(%\\w+)`: our match group, picking any number of characters that are in [a-zA-Z_] prefixed with %